# How can I test exceptions within functions built with node-redis using vitest?

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest, node-redis, vitest

I am trying to test a piece of code which implements both Event (Fire-and-Forget) and Message (Request-Reply) pattern using `node-redis` NPM package. I am using [`vitest`](https://vitest.dev/) to write the tests.Being quite new to testing with `vitest` (even `jest`), I have written a successfull test but failed to write the test where exception can be tested and hence need help.

In simplest form my code is as follows:

```js
/*** redisCall.ts ***/

import { createClient } from 'redis';

export const redisCall = async (
    host: string,
    port: number,
    channel: string,
    data: Record<string, any>,
    pattern: string = 'event',
    replyChannel: string = 'replyChannel'
) => {
    let reply = null;
    let url = `redis://${host}:${port}`;

    const redisClient = createClient({ url });

    redisClient.on('error', (error) => {
        throw String(error);
    });
    await redisClient.connect();
    await redisClient.publish(channel, JSON.stringify(data));

    if (pattern === 'message') {
        const subscriber = redisClient.duplicate();
        subscriber.on('error', (error) => {
            throw String(error);
        });
        await subscriber.connect();

        const waitForReply = () =>
            new Promise(async (resolve) => {
                const listener = async (message: any) => {
                    resolve(message);
                };
                await subscriber.subscribe(replyChannel, listener);
            });
        reply = await waitForReply();
        await subscriber.unsubscribe(replyChannel);
        await subscriber.disconnect();
    }
    await redisClient.disconnect();
    return reply;
};
```

And my test(s) are:

```js
/*** redisCall.test.ts ***/

import { afterEach, expect, vi, describe, it, test } from 'vitest';
import { createClient } from 'redis';
import { redisCall } from './redisCall.js';

const mockOn = vi.fn();
const mockConnect = vi.fn();
const mockPublish = vi.fn();
const mockDisconnect = vi.fn();
const mockUnsubscribe = vi.fn();
const mockSubscribe = vi.fn((_replyChannel, listener) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        listener(JSON.stringify({ reply: 'This is a reply' }));
    }, 100);
});
const mockDuplicate = vi.fn(() => ({
    on: mockOn,
    connect: mockConnect,
    subscribe: mockSubscribe,
    unsubscribe: mockUnsubscribe,
    disconnect: mockDisconnect,
}));

vi.mock('redis', () => ({
    createClient: vi.fn(() => ({
        on: mockOn,
        connect: mockConnect,
        publish: mockPublish,
        disconnect: mockDisconnect,
        duplicate: mockDuplicate,
    })),
}));

afterEach(() => {
    vi.clearAllMocks();
});

test('should publish data as event', async () => {
    await redisCall('localhost', 6379, 'testChannel', { key: 'value' });
    expect(createClient).toHaveBeenCalledOnce();
    expect(createClient).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ url: 'redis://localhost:6379' });
    expect(mockConnect).toHaveBeenCalledOnce();
    expect(mockDisconnect).toHaveBeenCalledOnce();
    expect(mockOn).toHaveBeenCalledWith('error', expect.any(Function));
    expect(mockPublish).toHaveBeenCalledWith('testChannel', JSON.stringify({ key: 'value' }));
});

test('should publish data as message', async () => {
    await redisCall('localhost', 6379, 'testChannel', { key: 'value' }, 'message');
    expect(createClient).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(createClient).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ url: 'redis://localhost:6379' });
    expect(mockDuplicate).toHaveBeenCalledOnce();
    expect(mockConnect).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
    expect(mockDisconnect).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
    expect(mockOn).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
    expect(mockOn).toHaveBeenCalledWith('error', expect.any(Function));
    expect(mockPublish).toHaveBeenCalledWith('testChannel', JSON.stringify({ key: 'value' }));
    expect(mockSubscribe).toBeCalledWith('replyChannel', expect.any(Function));
    expect(mockUnsubscribe).toHaveBeenCalledOnce();
});
```

Please could anyone help in writing test for testing the statement `redisClient.on('error', (error) => { throw String(error);});` in the `redisCall.ts` file above.

I tried looking in vitest documentation and jest documentation. Also looked at jest examples for error testing in stackoverflow. Not much luck.